# How can i solve error this like Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

I was decompiling I solved every problem but I have 7 lines like this have same problem I just got these problems I solved the others. I terribly need help. I'm kinda new btw.

```
dst[dstOffset] = (this.m_buffer[offset + i] ^ key[(offset + i) % 8]);
```

Comment: Your question, as asked cannot be answered. You really need to specify the type of `dst`, `m_buffer` and `key`. I'm going to guess that they are `byte[]`. In C# when you perform arithmetic or logical operations on integral types, the values get promoted to `int` (or in some cases, `long`). You need to surround everything on the right-hand side in parentheses (one set), and the cast it `(byte)`. `(byte) ((this.m_buffer[offset + i] ^ key[(offset + i) % 8]))`

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side of your assignment operation is producing an `int` value and, as the error message indicates, `dst[dstOffset]` on the left hand side is of type `byte`.

Cast the `int` value to `byte` before assigning, like -

```
dst[dstOffset] = (byte)(this.m_buffer[offset + i] ^ key[(offset + i) % 8]);
```